# Error in event when there is no charge option

Tags: civievent, payment-processor, stripe

I have an event setup with two pricing options one for members and the other for non-members. The members price is $0he non-member is charged $35. When someone selects the Member option at no charge the following error comes up:

Payment Error Response:

- Error: Could not find payment information

If they select the non-member option the payment block loads and the registration processes fine.

This is CiviCRM 4.7.23 with WordPress 4.8 and Stripe payment processor (ver 4.7.1)

Comment: Can you try another payment processor - to confirm this is Stripe specific; use dmaster demo -> dummy payment processor e.g.

Comment: Seems to be Stripe related, however if I add a Pay Later option the issue is resolved.